# I would like to know how to implement a layout that has static labels and dynamic data underneath them on my android phone

Tags: android, layout, graphics, dynamic

I am working on an app right now that takes in data from inputstream and displays it, but I would like to know, specifically in XML, how or where, I can learn to create a display to the user that shows static labels with the data coming in from the stream underneath them, constantly being updated. I believe I want to use a relative layout. The bold letters are the static labels, and the italics are the dynamic values that I get from the stream. Please help. Thank you.

Example: **Temperature**    **Volts**  **Tachometer**

```
           *20*    *12*   *4000*
```

Answer (score 0):

forgive me if my answer is not what you were hoping, because I can't think of any way to do this purely in XML. But, until a better answer comes along, here's how I've been doing a similar thing:

In the activity that is going to be displaying the results, let there be a Handler object, and private Runnable classes which each update an element of the UI.

```
/** Handler for callbacks to the UI thread */
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

/** Runnable class to be posted in handler */
private class SetTemperatureText implements Runnable {
    private final int newTemp;
    public SetTemperatureText(int newTemp) {
        this.newTemp = newTemp;
    }
    public void run() {
        mTemperatureTextView.setText(newTemp + " degrees C");
    }
}
```

You could have one of these for each dynamically changing field.

Elsewhere in the same activity, you spawn a new thread to deal with the incoming input. Whenever it obtains a new value for one of the fields, have it create a new SetWhateverField object with the new value and post it to the Handler. The UI thread will shortly come along and update the UI with the new value.

As for the layout itself, a RelativeLayout doesn't sound like a bad idea. A TableLayout might work well, too:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

It was hard for me to tell whether you needed more information on xml/layout structure or on methods of dynamically updating UI elements. If you clarify this, maybe I (and everyone else) will be able to help you more.

Comment: @ Cephron Thank you very much Cephron. I have more questions though. If the code you submitted above is for the dynamically changing text, how would I implement the code to see a label above that dynamic number? How do I line them up and place them where I want? I would like to do as much of the layout in XML, but if I have to do it in java, I just need to know how. I could not submit my design via a jpg because of my rep level, but would you mind if I emailed it to you so you could get a better idea of what I am trying to accomplish? Thanks again.

Comment: I would rather keep my email private, but I'm pretty sure the layout you need can be done purely in XML. For starters, I think you might benefit from looking at some TableLayout examples. (A quick web search got me
http://androiddevel.blogspot.com/2007/12/tablelayout-example.html
and
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#tablelayout )
Perhaps a TableRow of labels with a TableRow of updating values beneath it would work? Remember that you can always embed the TableLayout into a larger layout.

Comment: I figured out the layout and that I want to use your way of updating the UI after a lot of research on ListView. Could you explain in a little more detail what you mean by spawning a new thread and where these declarations would go in my main activity? Can they be separate class files in my package and then be called as runnable classes? I have separate classes running in separate applications, but I need to put them together in the same app. Please don't be sorry about anything. Any helps is very much appreciated.